# Eclipse often opens editors for hex numbers (addresses?) then fails to load anything

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Fairly often, usaually when starting/restarting programs in the debugger, I get editor tabs opening automatically for hex numbers. These predictably can't find anything to open:

[image: Strange hex number editor]

This is very annoying, as it will interrupt you while you are writing in another tab. If you switch back to your old editor tab, it will then clutter up the tab list.

I've seen this for years on many different machines, both on straight Eclipse CDT and custom Eclipse-based IDEs like TI Code Composer Studio.

Currently seeing it on Eclipse CDT Neon and CCS 6.2.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a symptom of stopping on an address with no debug information of any kind.

As it turns out, it is on my list to do for CDT 9.3. Follow progress on [Bug 515296](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515296)

Comment: Thank you! I always assumed it was a config issue and therefore user error, especially as no-one else ever seems to mention it!